# How to grab an image and save it in a folder [c# windows application]

Tags: c#, windows, image, screen-grab

I am Creating an windows application using c#.I have a button which should capture the image(the entire Desktop screen) and Save it in a folder .Also i need to show the preview of the image .

Comment: What is the problem? What is the error? What have you tried?  Your ""question"" is just a statement.

Comment: How to Capture the desktop screen and save the image in a folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Graphics.CopyFromScreen Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen.aspx)

sample code:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);
g.Save();
bmp.Save("D:\\file.jpg", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

as for show the preview. IMO not that hard to write it on ur own.

Comment: Nikko   , what about if i want to save the displayed image as its full resolution ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Cant do that with Graphics.CopyFromScreen method. this method just copies a part of screen to destination. it has no knowledge of displayed image's full resolution.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to perform what you bring here. Using the [`Screen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx) class, there are a few simple samples I found on the Internet. Others are using Direct3D.

1. [TeboScreen: Basic C# Screen Capture Application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/TeboScreen.aspx);
2. [Capture a Screen Shot](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4630/capture-a-screen-shot/);
3. [C# – Screen capture with Direct3D](http://spazzarama.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/screencapture-with-direct3d/);
4. [Capture DeskTop Screen](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/16829-Capture-DeskTop-Screen.aspx);
5. [Enhanced Desktop Recorder in .NET using C# and Windows Forms](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/satisharveti/EnhancedDesktopRecorder07222008041309AM/EnhancedDesktopRecorder.aspx); (perhaps not suited for your question, but might get interesting if you plan further features.)
6. [Capturing the Screen Image Using C#](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_graphics/screencaptures/article.php/c6139).

In short, the idea consists of getting the image of the desktop using the `Screen` class or your favorite way, store it into a [`Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) object and save this bitmap into a file.

As for displaying a preview, once your `Bitmap` instance is created, you simply need a [`PictureBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx) and set its [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image.aspx) property and show your form to the user so he may see the image.

Hope this helps! =)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do some importing of Interop dlls.

Take a look at the following [example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/perrylee/ScreenCapture11142005234547PM/ScreenCapture.aspx) shows very well how to capture the screen shot and save to disk.

```
public void CaptureScreen(string fileName,ImageFormat imageFormat)
{
    int hdcSrc = User32.GetWindowDC(User32.GetDesktopWindow()),
    hdcDest = GDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc),
    hBitmap = GDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc,
    GDI32.GetDeviceCaps(hdcSrc,8),GDI32.GetDeviceCaps(hdcSrc,10));                 GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest,hBitmap);
    GDI32.BitBlt(hdcDest,0,0,GDI32.GetDeviceCaps(hdcSrc,8),
    GDI32.GetDeviceCaps(hdcSrc,10),hdcSrc,0,0,0x00CC0020);
    SaveImageAs(hBitmap,fileName,imageFormat);
    Cleanup(hBitmap,hdcSrc,hdcDest);
}
```

The above example taken from the website. All code by Perry Lee

Comment: from the link u've posted /* Author: Perry Lee
* Submission: Capture Screen (Add Screenshot Capability to Programs)
* **Date of Submission: 12/29/03**
*/



no need to load all those dll. that code is a bit obsolete.

with .net2.0 and above things are much easier

Comment: @Niko, true. net net has come a long way, and .net 4 improves even more.